# Issue in getting complex object in Web API Post

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm making ajax POST call to my web API and posting a JSON. Below is my code

**C# class:**

```
    public class Employee:EmployeeBase
{
    private string _EId;
    private string _EName;
    private string _Designation;
    private EmployeeBase[] _Expirence;

    public string EId
    {
        get { return _EId; }
        set { _EId = value; }
    }
    public string EName
    {
        get { return _EName; }
        set { _EName = value; }
    }
    public string Designation
    {
        get { return _Designation; }
        set { _Designation = value; }
    }
    public Expirence[] MyExpirence
    {
        get { return _Expirence; }
        set { _Expirence = value; }
    }
}

public class EmployeeBase
{
     private string _Id;
     private string _Company;
     private string _Years;

    public string Id
    {
        get { return _Id; }
        set { _Id = value; }
    }
    public string Company
    {
        get { return _Company; }
        set { _Company = value; }
    }
    public string Years
    {
        get { return _Years; }
        set { _Years = value; }
    }
 }
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveAssociatDisassociateCameras(Employee zone)
{
}
```

**Sample JSON:**

**Sample 1 :**

```
{  
   "Id":"E100",
   "Name":"TestEmployee",
   "Designation":"Test Engineer",
   "MyExpirence":[  
      {  
         "Id":"01",
         "Company":"Company1",
         "Years":"10"
      }
   ]
}
```

**Sample 2 :**

```
{  
   "Id":"E100",
   "Name":"TestEmployee",
   "Designation":"Test Engineer",
   "MyExpirence":[  
      {  
         "Id":"01",
         "Company":"Company1",
         "Years":"10"
      }
   ],
   "DummyArray":[  

   ]
}
```

Now the issue is when I post **Sample 1** JSON is getting properly posted to controller. But in controller MyExpirence array is null. But I'm getting values for EId,EName etc. Only MyExpirence array is null.

In other hand if I post  **Sample 2** adding a dummy array to the JSON I'm getting proper values. In this case I'm getting proper value for EId,EName and even for MyExpirence array.

I cant understand why I'm getting null for MyExpirence in Sample 1. And I'm not okay with the Sample 2 solution. I want a correct way of doing this.

Comment: Not the answer, but `Expirence` is spelled `Experience`

Comment: Why are you deriving `Employee` from `EmployeeBase`?

Comment: Post the Code for this class: Expirence, The one used in MyExpirence[]

Comment: Why your Experience matches EmployeeBase?

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't compile: `_Expirence` is different to `MyExpirence` property. Fix it like in next sample

```
public class Employee:EmployeeBase
{
    private string _EId;
    private string _EName;
    private string _Designation;
    private EmployeeBase[] _Expirence;

    public string EId
    {
        get { return _EId; }
        set { _EId = value; }
    }
    public string EName
    {
        get { return _EName; }
        set { _EName = value; }
    }
    public string Designation
    {
        get { return _Designation; }
        set { _Designation = value; }
    }
    public Expirence[] MyExpirence
    {
        get { return _Expirence; }
        set { _Expirence = value; }
    }
}
```